# $f\circ g=g\circ f$ and continuity

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose we have two complex functions $f$ and $g$ such that $f$ is continuous and $f\circ g=g\circ f$ is continuous too. Is $g$ necessarily continuous?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

No. Take $f=0$ and any function $g$ such that $g(0)=0$. Hence $f\circ g = 0$ and $g \circ f = 0$ too.

Answer (score 1):

Take $f(z) = 1$ for all $z$, $g(z) = \begin{cases} 1, & z=1 \\ 0, & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$.

Then $f(g(z)) = 1$, $g(f(z)) = 1$, but $g$ is clearly not continuous.

Comment: Ok, and what if f is not constant?